# Приложение не отправляет запрос на сервер на версии android выше 8.1, хотя в SDK установлена 10.0

Tags: java, android

Сделал приложение, простой клиент для школьного портала. В приложении используются post запросы на сервер, на версии android 8.1 и ниже все прекрасно работает, но когда я отправляю запрос на версии 9.0 приложение просто его не отправляет. Чекал запросы через packet capture, ничего не выдает. Без понятия что делать.

Comment: может код приложите, адрес ресурса?

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя протокол `http`, то добавь в манифест:

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

И в папку `res/xml` добавь файл

***network_security_config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomen.ru</domain> // Сюда вставь свой домен
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```